# How to provide security for the password using spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring. My requirement is:
I need to get the user name and password in my component class. validate it with by invoking the webservices available at my client.
So I want to provide security to my password which can not be directly visible anywhere.
So how to implement this?
Please give suggestions

Comment: This question is too broad to give any useful answers. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i get the user name and password. and i also can be able to validate with the returned values from webservices.

Comment: Ok, and what do you want to do?

Comment: but is there any way can i provide security to my password?

Comment: What do you mean with "security"? There are several ways like hashing the password, using only encrypted connections etc. But nobody can tell you without more details (like code for example).

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security can participate in many different authentication environments. While we recommend people use Spring Security for authentication and not integrate with existing Container Managed Authentication, it is nevertheless supported - as is integrating with your own proprietary authentication system.

**What is authentication in Spring Security?**

Let's consider a standard authentication scenario that everyone is familiar with.

A user is prompted to log in with a username and password.

The system (successfully) verifies that the password is correct for the username.

The context information for that user is obtained (their list of roles and so on).

A security context is established for the user

The user proceeds, potentially to perform some operation which is potentially protected by an access control mechanism which checks the required permissions for the operation against the current security context information.

The first three items constitute the authentication process so we'll take a look at how these take place within Spring Security.

The username and password are obtained and combined into an instance of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (an instance of the Authentication interface, which we saw earlier).

The token is passed to an instance of AuthenticationManager for validation.

The AuthenticationManager returns a fully populated Authentication instance on successful authentication.

The security context is established by calling SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(...), passing in the returned authentication object.

This could help: http://www.viddler.com/v/c596114a